# meaning of つい先ほど

Tags: grammar

先ほど　can mean, depending on the context, "just now" or "some time ago"

つい means "just"

but in this case, what brings つい to the sentence, since the "just" is normally conveyed in the 先ほど　 ?

Context:　the protagonist has just died

> 佐藤和真さん、ようこそ死後の世界へ。あなたは**つい先ほど**、不幸にも亡くなりました
>
> Kazuma Satou ... Welcome to the Great Beyond. I am sorry to tell you
> that you've passed on.

Comment: `くなりましたくなりました` -- You meant to type 亡くなりました?

Comment: yes, I have just corrected. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the context, 先ほど can refer to something that happened one hour ago, but つい先ほど refers to something that **just** happened. You may want to think 先ほど is "a while ago" and つい先ほど is "just a while ago".

Answer (score 1):

先ほど means earlier, and it can be 1 hour earlier or 1 minute.
Here in this case つい is explaining 先ほど.
つい means a little bit (in time or in dostance) and here explaining how much ealier (先ほど) he died.
So つい先ほど means a little bit earlier, which is equal to just now.
I think English translation missed it.